# class is-a-JPanel when it should have-a

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, netbeans

When Netbeans extends JPanel, does that create problems when referencing instances of the auto-generated class because it uses inheritance rather than composition?

Because Netbeans declares JPanels as `private javax.swing.JPanel overview;` the instance then has a type of JPanel, when it should have a type of Overview.

How can I invoke the setGroup method and yet keep Overview as an autogenerated JPanel?  I try as so:

Main.java

```
private void groupsPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    String s = evt.getNewValue().toString();
    LOG.fine("new group: " + s);
    overview.setGroup(s);
}
```

with Overview.java:

```
public class Overview extends javax.swing.JPanel {


...

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

}
```

but get this compile error:

```
init:
Deleting: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/SwingNNTP/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/SwingNNTP/build/built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to /home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/SwingNNTP/build/classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/SwingNNTP/src/net/bounceme/dur/nntp/view/Main.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
        overview.setGroup(s);
  symbol:   method setGroup(String)
  location: variable overview of type JPanel
1 error
1 warning
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/SwingNNTP/nbproject/build-impl.xml:628: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/SwingNNTP/nbproject/build-impl.xml:285: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate the Overview class?

Comment: Overview instantiated in the Main class, but it's so spammy that I omitted it because it's autogenerated; it's in the `initComponents` method.

Comment: I think there is your problem. Look at the error: `location: variable overview of type JPanel`. overview is a variable of your panel. You did not instantiate a Overview object.

Comment: it's declared of that type.  how do I change the declaration in the GUI builder?

Comment: Sorry, but I think you should read a bit into java programming instead using a GUI builder and expect that everything works out of the box.

Comment: it's declared of type JPanel and instantiated as so:  `overview = new net.bounceme.dur.nntp.view.Overview();` I was just asking how to declare it as of type Overview.

Comment: I think the variable is of type `JPanel`, not `Overview`- Use `net.bounceme.dur.nntp.view.Overview overview = new net.bounceme.dur.nntp.view.Overview();`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10959/discussion-between-thufir-and-stephan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `JPanel` with a suitable [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) is a convenient `Container` for one or more `JComponent` instances. It provides a (basic) UI delegate and double buffering, but little else. Custom components should probably extend `JComponent` directly. The infrastructure for an (optional) UI delegate is shown [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html). You can add such custom components to the designer palette as discussed [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormUsingCustomComponent).

Comment: tools->Palette->Swing/AWT Componets, then choose "add from project" and select a class which extends, in this case, JPanel?  Even after clean and build no classes appear in this window.  Neither do any classes in the "build" folder.  Still looking into it, thank you.

Comment: @Thufir: I'm afraid I haven't gone too far down that rabbit hole, but there's more [here](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-palette-api2.html).

Comment: Thank you, I should've googled that first!  I'll take a look in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess Netbeans doesn't have such an option of declaring a JPanel created with the GUI as any type other than JPanel, which is kinda odd. Why extend JPanel if, staying with the Netbeans GUI builder, you can't instantiate a sub-class of JPanel with that extended type?  Not that extending JPanel is intrinsically a good idea...

solution code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp.view;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class MyTabs extends JTabbedPane {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyTabs.class.getName());
    private Overview overview = new Overview();
    private Detail details = new Detail();
    private Groups groups = new Groups();

    public MyTabs() {
        this.add("groups", groups);
        this.add("overview", overview);
        this.add("detail", details);

        groups.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {

            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                String s = evt.getNewValue().toString();
                LOG.fine(s);
                overview.setGroup(s);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I'm just curious if there's some better way of doing this, other than not using the GUI builder.

Comment: +1 for loose coupling; you can also listen to the tabbed pane's `model`. As an aside, it's a _GUI_ designer, not an _application_ designer. :-)